# Create a jQuery Countdown Timer which resets after intervals

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

I want to create a jQuery Countdown Timer, to which i'll pass a time, it will show counter to that time and then resets to count one hour and then resets to count next 23 hours and then resets to one hour loop continues.

I am taking a quiz on a certain date, quiz will open for one hour, then next quiz will start after 23 hours.

Can anyone help..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples.html)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="clock"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var fiveSeconds = new Date().getTime() + 5000;
$('#clock').countdown(fiveSeconds, {elapse: true})
.on('update.countdown', function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (event.elapsed) {
    $this.html(event.strftime('After end: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
  } else {
    $this.html(event.strftime('To end: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanx for the help, but how do I reset it to count for next 1 hour and after that reset it for next 23 hours and so on..?

Comment: Loop thrugh that function